# Pass-word not being accepted for google on my Android phone

Tags: google

My google password on my desktop computer is correct and I can access google through it, but when I enter my google password on my Android phone it says that,

> Username and password do not match.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try creating an app specific password and see whether the issue persists?

Comment: Do you have multiple Google accounts? Maybe your primary account on the Android device is not the same you're using on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.
Try changing your password and try logging in again from phone.

Comment: That's a very **bold** claim. It is absolutely possible if the Google account is protected with two-step-verification. This may be either another case where OP is typing wrong password, or OP has checked "remember me" for two step verification on Desktop, and possibly missed that phone wouldn't work simply by entering password. In that case, app specific password is the best thing to use if the Google Account Settings in phone doesn't supports two step verification.

Comment: It's indeed a very bold claim – especially considering the few facts known. Who tells you the two accounts are similar? Or think of different keyboard layouts, where mistypings occur quite easily. Skipping the first 3 words, it might make a good comment, though :)